# htaccess redirect 301 from weird wordpress url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

there was a wordpress. I made a new website. Google and Bing show former addresses.
I decided to redirect from old url to new ones with a htaccess.

If I write this :
`Redirect 301 /a-propos/ https://www.thedomaine.org/index.php`
it is working.

But if I write that :
`/index.php/a-propos/`
it is not working. But it was the wordpress link memorized by search engines.

If I have `Redirect 301 /xxxxx/ https://www.thedomaine.org/index.php` it's ok
If I have `Redirect 301 /xxxxx/yyyyy/ https://www.thedomaine.org/index.php`it's not working

I tried other apache language kinds of directions, I tried to say I dont care what is before the last word... Nothing worked

I lost hours to find a solution.
Thank you very much for your clear and simple solution or your explanation for what's wrong.

Comment: So, the old URL is `/index.php/a-propos` and the new URL is just `/index.php`? That is "unusual" (not recommended) for the new URL? "I tried other apache language kinds of directions" - so, what specifically did you try and where? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? You will likely need to use mod_rewrite, but the order of directives is important.